# Running flask server with tkinter

Tags: python, flask, tkinter

I got simple tkinter gui with a button. The target is when the button is clicked, flask server should be started. If I put flask inside button function, flask runs perfectly, but tkinter gui turns not responding. If I put the flask server in another script, it shows console which I want to hide and if I turn another script to pyw, it ends as soon as it starts. what should I do?

Comment: You will need to start the flask server on another thread, so that it does not block the tkinter GUI.